# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: lex

I am trying to compile this lex program but the i am getting this message

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ll
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to compile by typing this

```
cc first.yy.c -oexe -ly
```

Comment: Because it is a linker error we need to see the command you are using to link it.

Comment: And you might want to look in /use/bin and /use/local/bin for libl.a because that is where the linker will look by default.

Comment: Question edited @JerryJeremiah

Comment: That command doesn't mention `-ll` so it seems like the error comes from a different build command, perhaps the one where you compile your scanner. Most of the time, you want to link the parser and the scanner into a single executable, though. So that build procedure seems wrong.

Comment: The compile command you included in the question is for the yacc output file.  What do you use to compile the lex file?

Comment: Some distributions require that you use `-lfl` (the flex version of that library). Some make you install the `flex-devel` package (or equivalent). But the easiest solution is generally to avoid the need for the library altogether by using `%option noyywrap`. (`libl` also includes a simple `main`, but if you are using yacc/bison in your project, the `main` in `libl` won't help you anyway. Make sure you have a `main()` somewhere.)